# jQuery: Timeout after trigger()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I using a mesh of organic tabs and a image rotator. When the user clicks on one of the thumbnails, the image rotator stops auto-advancing. When the user clicks on a tab, the auto-advance starts again. However, without a timeout or pause, the auto-advance may change simultaniously when the user clicks on a tab.

jQuery Code:

```
current=-1;
$('.years li:first a', tab).trigger('click',[true]);
current=1;
```

Current is used as a flag. When it's -1, the auto-advance function will return false. How do I add a delay before setting current to 1? I was thinking something like:

```
$('.years li:first a', tab).trigger('click',[true]).setTimeout(function(){current=1},1000);
```

But this obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` isn't jQuery and therefore cannot be chained with jQuery objects.  If you detach that `setTimeout` you should be fine.

Additionally, you will probably want to clear that timeout in the event that the user stops the rotate again before you can set current.  So you'll want to do something like this:

```
var timer;

...

timer = setTimeout(...);

...

// when the rotation is stopped, clear the timer in case it hasn't triggered yet
clearTimeout(timer);
```